# Flyway custom MigrationResolver

Tags: java, spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

Previously I was using flyway version 7.15.0 and I created MigrationResolver like this

```
public class ApplicationContextAwareMigrationResolver implements MigrationResolver {

  @Override
  public Collection<ResolvedMigration> resolveMigrations(Context context) {
    List<ResolvedMigration> migrations = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<String, JavaMigration> migrationBeans =
        this.applicationContext.getBeansOfType(JavaMigration.class);

    for (JavaMigration javaMigration : migrationBeans.values()) {
      ResolvedMigrationImpl resolvedMigration = new ResolvedJavaMigration(javaMigration);
      migrations.add(resolvedMigration);
    }

    migrations.sort(new ResolvedMigrationComparator());
    return migrations;
  }
}
```

After upgrading to version 9.22.3 ResolvedJavaMigration does not exist in import org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.java.ResolvedJavaMigration;

From the documentation: 'getResolvedMigration' method on Java Migrations interface now takes a StatementInterceptor

I could not find a solution to how I can create ResolvedMigrationImpl in version 9.22.3.

I tried like this:

```
ResolvedMigration resolvedMigration = javaMigration.getResolvedMigration(new ClassicConfiguration(), StatementInterceptor)
```

I don't know how to create StatementInterceptor

Comment: Hey @KiKo, any sucess with this?